# With Electron, is there a way to distinguish between user clicking on the menu item and using the keyboard shortcut?

Tags: google-analytics, electron

With Electron, is there a way to distinguish between user clicking on the menu item and using the keyboard shortcut?

I know that the expected behavior for both is generally the same, but I'd like to track the usage of shortcuts and menu clicks separately.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this directly. The `event` parameter of MenuItem's [`click`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/menu-item#new-menuitemoptions) handler doesn't have a property that indicates whether the action was invoked through mouse or keyboard.

### Workaround

However, you can of course use a workaround, using the fact that if a menu function is triggered using the keyboard shortcut, the pressing of the key(s) can be simultaneously captured from the renderer process using the [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event) event.

In its easiest form, you could track *all calls* to the menu function, i.e. disregarding whether they were invoked through mouse or keyboard. In parallel, you listen for the same shortcuts in your renderer. Whenever a shortcut is detected that is also an accelerator in your menu, you make a note of this.

### Example

Assuming a scenario where you use the mouse to click the action, then use the shortcut, and then the mouse again, the tracked events would be:

```
#  time  event
1   t0   Menu item action               (Using mouse)
2   t1   Menu item action               (Using keyboard shortcut)
3  ~t1   Keyboard shortcut detected
4   t2   Menu item action               (Using mouse)
```

If you have data like this, you can count the number of occurrences of "Menu item action" (here 3) and "Keyboard shortcut detected" (here 1). Then you know that 1 out of 3 times the menu action was invoked using the keyboard shortcut.

### Downsides

The downsides of this workaround are:

- Duplicated code for menu accelerators and key listener
- Generation of two events in case of keyboard use

One could think of possible ways to remedy these downsides, depending on your particular use case.

Comment: Actually, although I had a similar idea, we did figure out a better variation of this :) There is an option called `registerAccelerator` on `MenuItemConstructorOptions`. When you set it to false, it still renders the shortcut but doesn't react to it. That way you can react to shortcuts in renderer and track it all separately.